# FormBuilder - PHP notice Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: plugins, form, php

I'm trying to do a form, I'm using FormBuilder plugin.
I have the form and the fields, but when I try to acess ../admin/entries to manage the content of the page, I have this error, why is that? What did I miss?
I The code in that page:

```
{% block content %}
<h1>{{ entry.title }}</h1>
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" name="{{ form.handle }}" class="formbuilder-form" id="{{ form.handle }}" data-parsley-errors-container=".formbuilder-notification"{% if form.hasFileUploads %} enctype="multipart/form-data" {% endif %}>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="formBuilder/entries/saveFormEntry">
<input type="hidden" name="formredirect" data-redirect="{{form.successPageRedirect}}" value="{{form.redirectUrl}}">
<input type="hidden" name="formHandle" value="{{form.handle}}">

{% for tab in tabs %}
  {% set fields = tab.getFields() %}

  <fieldset class="{{loop.index}}">
    <legend>{{ tab.name }}</legend>
    {% for field in fields %}
      {% set input = craft.formBuilder.getInputHtml(field) %}
      {{ input | raw }}
    {% endfor %}
  </fieldset>
{% endfor %}

{# Error/Success Messages #}
{% if craft.session.hasFlash('error') or craft.session.hasFlash('success') %}
  {% if craft.session.hasFlash('error') %}<div class="formbuilder-notification"><p class="error-message">{{ craft.session.getFlash('error') | raw }}<p></div>{% endif %}
  {% if craft.session.hasFlash('success') %}<div class="formbuilder-notification success"><p class="success-message">{{ craft.session.getFlash('success') | raw }}</p></div>{% endif %}
{% else %}
  <div class="formbuilder-notification"></div>
{% endif %}

<button type="submit">Submit Message</button>


</form>

{% endblock %}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. My problem stemmed from the fact that I had put all of the form fields that I created into the field layout for my form page.

[image: Design Field Layout with Form Fields needing removal]

I was used to putting all the fields directly on to the page. Once I removed all the form fields from my field layout, I was able to successfully access the page to manage my content.

It seems as though your fields for forms should be treated separately and not put directly into the page. They should be added through the formbuilder plugin.

[image: Adding form fields using formbuilder correctly]